# Probability of picking 3 specific, different numbers from a sample of 100

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

How to calculate the probability of finding 3 specific numbers from the range 1-100 within a sample of 100 randomly generated numbers, with repetition, that is also in the 1-100? Order is not important in any context. An example is finding 1,5 and 7 among these 100 numbers.

I know the general formula for a combination with repetitions but my doubt is whether it should be adjusted because the 3 numbers are different, i.e. I am not looking for a triple repeat of one same number.

Comment: There are $100^3$ equally probable ordered triples, and there are $6$  ordered triples that correspond to your choice so...

Comment: Note:  it's useful to pretend that order matters since the ordered triples are equi-probable while the unordered ones are not...$\{1,2,3\}$ is six times more likely than $\{1,1,1\}$ for instance.

Comment: I think I phrased the question in a misleading way. The event is not generating 3 numbers from 1-100 range and checking if they fit the 3 targeted ones, but generating 100 random numbers from 1-100 and checking if the 3 targeted numbers are among them, wherever, i.e. ordering of the 100 sample and the 3 numbers among them is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, you are choosing $100$ numbers?  In that case, still working with ordered $100-$ tuples, I'd break it into cases.  Count those that have none of the required three.  Then those that have exactly one.  And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to compute the complementary probability $q$ that such a triple will not be realized. This will involve an inclusion/exclusion process. One obtains
$$q=3\cdot 0.99^{100}-3\cdot 0.98^{100}+0.97^{100}=0.747791\ .$$
Here the first term takes care of all cases where at least one of $1$, $2$, $5$ is missing, the second term takes care of the double counting of the cases where both $1$ and $2$, etc., are missing, and the third term throws in again the cases where all three numbers are missing. The probability $p$ you are after is therefore given by $$p=1-q=0.252209\ .$$